# Sending emoticons in android chating application through xmpp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, xmpp

I want to send the emoticon in my chatting application which is an android application and use's the XMPP server for sending and receiving the message.
So any one can just help hoe to send the emoticon..?

Comment: Use can do that using [these](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note1). And send the text using one of the codes like this: `messageInput.getText().append("\u07f9");` **OR** can use a [lib](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)

Comment: give me another suggestion...i am not able to get  what you said?

Comment: Could You give us a little bit more information? Show us what You have done and where You stuck....